# USB OTG DMA Attack vector, any information about that?

Tags: exploit, usb-drive

In that paper: http://www.delaat.net/rp/2011-2012/p14/report.pdf[1] is reported that USB OTG can be used to have direct DMA memory access and as a consequence have access to all the content of the memory of a device/computer.

I would like to know more about that attack vector.

Any idea about where can I find more information and/or some tool to exercise that attack vectors ?

Many thanks.

What I know are:

- M. Jodeit and M. Johns. “USB Device Drivers: A Stepping Stone into your Kernel”. In: Computer Network Defense (EC2ND), 2010 European Conference on. IEEE. 2010.
- D. Maynor. “0wn3d by everything else-USB/PCMCIA Issues”. In: Presentation at CanSecWest (2005).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In contrast to all the other buses mentioned, USB does not allow remote DMA; nowhere in the USB on-the-wire protocol are there memory addresses.
Only the driver and/or the OS can control from/to which memory addresses USB data is read/written.

OTG allows to change the roles of host and device, but does not change the USB protocol.

Jodeit/Johns talks only about bugs in USB device drivers.

Maynor talks about driver bugs, and then mentions something called "DMA attack", but gives *no* details *whatsoever*.
The most likely explanation is that he found some driver bug that allows the device to influence how the driver handles its memory buffers.
This would still be a bug in one specific driver, and has nothing to do with the remote DMA feature of other buses.

In other words: there is nothing dangerous about USB OTG itself, only with the quality of its drivers.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know how USB OTG works.  My understanding is that with USB OTG and USB protocol exploitation you can have access to DMA. I contacted Maynor on Twitter but he didn't reply yet. In summary by the way, seems that in the paper are used wrongs and not so clear assumption.

Comment: No, neither 'normal' USB nor ORG have remote DMA.

Comment: Do you know that because you know how USB works under the hood or what ?

Comment: Yes, I've written several USB drivers. BTW, the [USB specifications are public](http://www.usb.org/developers/).

Comment: Ok thank you. Maynor replied to some of my enquiries and he told me nothing basically. I know that USB specification are public but I can't allocate the necessary effort on the spec. I trust your explanation. Thank you.